# AS2 code to PHP code

Tags: php, flash, encryption, actionscript-2

I've tried to convert these functions from AS2 to PHP, but I've had no luck.

Here is the original AS2 function:

```
enc.charsToLongs = function (chars)
{
    var _loc3 = chars;
    var tlength = Math.ceil(_loc3.length / 4);
    var temp = [];
    var _loc2 = 0;
    for (var _loc1 = 0; _loc1 < tlength; ++_loc1)
    {
        _loc2 = _loc1 * 4;
        temp[_loc1] = (_loc3[_loc2] << 24) + (_loc3[_loc2 + 1] << 16) + (_loc3[_loc2 + 2] << 8) + _loc3[_loc2 + 3];
    } 
    return (temp);
};
```

This is what I have in PHP:

```
function charsToLongs($chars)
{

    $_loc3   = $chars;
    $tlength = ceil(count($_loc3) / 4);
    $temp    = array();
    $_loc2   = 0;
    for ($_loc1 = 0; $_loc1 < $tlength; $_loc1++) {
        $_loc2        = $_loc1 * 4;
        $temp[$_loc1] = ($_loc3[$_loc2] << 24) + ($_loc3[$_loc2 + 1] << 16) + ($_loc3[$_loc2 + 2] << 8) + $_loc3[$_loc2 + 3];
    }
    return ($temp);
}
```

Whenever I run the functions I get different answers for both. I know the AS2 one is working perfectly fine because I've used it many times to encrypt/decrypt strings perfectly fine. There are more functions too but this seems to be the only one I'm stuck on. Could someone tell me what's wrong?

Also: chars ($chars/chars) is an array of character ASCII values of the string I want to encrypt.

Thanks.

Comment: The AS2 code looks like you decompiled somebody's program, because decompilers generate such code.

Comment: your bitshift operators don't seem to match << / >>>

Comment: Zhafur: Irrelevant, but yes, I did decompile code that I was permitted to use, and it can be found on many websites too. ----- Will Kru: Thanks - that worked so far. ---- Also: I've updated the original post to show the new functions I'm having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ord()` and `chr()` (or `pack()` [if you want to be cache-timing safe](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/02/cryptographically-secure-php-development#chr)) to convert strings to ints in order to use bitshift operations.

```
// Wrong:
var_dump(
    ($_loc3[$_loc2] << 24) + ($_loc3[$_loc2 + 1] << 16) + ($_loc3[$_loc2 + 2] << 8) + $_loc3[$_loc2 + 3]
);

// Right:
var_dump(
    (ord($_loc3[$_loc2]) << 24) + (ord($_loc3[$_loc2 + 1]) << 16) + (ord($_loc3[$_loc2 + 2]) << 8) + ord($_loc3[$_loc2 + 3])
);
```

[See the output here](https://3v4l.org/Y7C24).